# AppleScript copy files from a to b with any user name

Tags: applescript, relative-path, file-copying

I'm trying to copy all files from a folder to another.
This works only if I specify the full path including the name of the drive and the username.

This works:

```
tell application "Finder"
set a to folder "Macintosh HD:Users:Michael:Desktop:Files:"
set b to folder "Macintosh HD:Users:Michael:Desktop:Copies"
duplicate every file of a to b
```

end tell

But I want to have this compatible with any HDD naming and username.
So I'm looking for a relative path, equivalent to `~:Desktop`.

Answer (score 2):

The relative path equivalent is

```
set desktopFolder to path to desktop
tell application "Finder"
    set a to folder "Files:" of desktopFolder
    set b to folder "Copies:" of desktopFolder
    duplicate every file of a to b
end tell
```

But the Finder has a property `desktop` which points always to the desktop folder of the current user.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set a to folder "Files:" of desktop
    set b to folder "Copies:" of desktop
    duplicate every file of a to b
end tell
```

And – even shorter – the desktop folder of the current user is the "root" folder of the Finder

```
tell application "Finder"
    duplicate every file of folder "Files" to folder "Copies"
end tell
```

**Edit:**

The equivalent to

`~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iWork.Numbers/Data/Library/Application Support/User Templates`

is

`((path to library folder from user domain as text) & "Containers:com.apple.iWork.Numbers:Data:Library:Application Support:User Templates:")`

Comment: Thank you @vadian but what if the destination is not on the desktop but in a deeper path in the user library?

Comment: This path to be exact: ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iWork.Numbers/Data/Library/Application Support/User Templates